# When I click the image button, the console displays undefined

Tags: reactjs, button, onclick, event-handling

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Person from "./Person.js";

class App extends Component {
  clickHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = event.target.value;
    console.log(data);
  };
  url =
    "https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.eBSw-Azi3SfBlttoGOip1gHaEr?w=297&h=187&c=7&r=0&o=5&dpr=1.3&pid=1.7";
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div onClick={this.clickHandler}>Test1</div>
        <Person clickHandler={this.clickHandler}>Test2</Person>
        <button type="button" value="Dog" onClick={this.clickHandler}>
          <img src={this.url} alt="Funny Dog" />
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

As you can see, I have defined the value of the button, and when I click on it, the console should display "Dog". Why is it showing "Undefined"?

Comment: Could you please provide me with a solution, bro?

Comment: What do you expect to see here? event.target -> refers to image that is being clicked and since it doesn't have any value property it logs out as undefined. Try logging event.target.src it'll print the value of src

Comment: I want to get the button value when I click the button, not src.

Comment: import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button
          type="button"
          value="Dog"
          onClick={this.clickHandler}
          style={{width: '100px', height: '100px', backgroundImage: `url("https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.eBSw-Azi3SfBlttoGOip1gHaEr?w=297&h=187&c=7&r=0&o=5&dpr=1.3&pid=1.7")` }}
        >
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;

Comment: What you basically want to do, is show image either on the background of the button, on create a div with background image and then use onClick on it. 

Nesting an image inside a button gets the click on the image and not the button even if the onClick is written on the button.

'Event Bubbling' and 'Event Propagation' is what you want to look into, if you want to understand this.

Comment: More easier approach is to just use 'const data = event.currentTarget.value;' which basically tells the element on which event listener is attached to (button in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const data = event.currentTarget.value;
```

Use currentTarget instead of target.
The difference between target and eventTarget is that eventTarget gives the element on which event listener is attached while target gives the element on which user has clicked.